# What is Hermite data?

Tags: definition, interpolation

Using fairly simple language, what is Hermite data? I encountered it here,
http://www.frankpetterson.com/publications/dualcontour/dualcontour.pdf and could not get an answer on standard StackExchange, who 'referred' me to here.

Comment: I've been reading this article recently and have no clue what a hermite data is.
But for this article specifically, I think the author already given a explanation for hermite data in its abstract:
Hermite data (i.e; **exact intersection points and normals**) hope this would help

Answer (score 5):

Hermite data is the value of a function and all its derivatives up to some order at all points of a data set. It is used in [Hermite interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_interpolation).

If you do not supply all the derivatives for all points, then you have *Birkhoff data*, also called *Hermite–Birkhoff*, which of course is used in [Birkhoff interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birkhoff_interpolation).

Comment: "derivatives up to some order" ... for us stupid people .. what does that mean?

Comment: It means that you store the value at some point, but also how this value changes at that point, and how this change of value changes etc

Comment: And for even more stupids, like me, in case of Dual Contouring?

Comment: @ПетърПетров I am no expert on this, but since Dual Contouring focuses on rendering isosurfaces (surfaces of the form $f(x, y, z) = 0$) That you must have an algorithm that computes $f(x, y, z)$ for all $(x, y, z)$ in the domain, and you must have an algorithm that computes the derivative of $f(x, y, z)$ at every $(x, y, z)$ in the domain.